# Can you claim past unclaimed expenses from previous years on a rental property?

Tags: taxes, canada, tax-deduction, rental-property, expenses

My question is the following:

Let's say I have some repair renovations that were performed in 2016 that I never claimed in the 2017 tax year (because I had enough expenses to fully balance out the rental income such that there was no profit or loss).

Would I be able to claim those unused 2016 repair renovations as expenses toward the 2018 tax year?

Or should I just claim every expense incurred in a particular year even if it leads to a rental income loss? In this case, how do I actually defer rental income losses to future years?